# Laravel scopeSearch Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have used a scopeSearch

- My model: History

public function scopeSearch($query, $term)

```
    $result = $query->where('user_id', 'like', '%' .$term. '%');
    return result;
```

I have used a search bar in my history view, users can input their ID and if there are id related to the history, it will display their histories.

```
tables:
'users' - columns: name, ...
'histories' -columns: user_id, ...
```

**My scopeSearch works if a user searches for an ID. I want users to type a name, not their IDs and their histories will be shown.**

The problem is there is only user_id in 'histories'

How do I work with this Eloquent?

I have tried typing weird stuffs with tinker and modified a little in the scopeSearch function by getting all of the data in 'users' but it did't work. I am totally weak in relationships. Sorry if I sound greedy.

[Update] I was advised to use a join method, I'm currently trying it

Comment: Do the user login to use this search? If not how do you know who the user is?

Comment: that is not necessary, this scopeSearch is only to filter histories according to what the user inputs. Are you suggesting a method with authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not to simply move scopeSearch into User model?

since the search query is based on users table, you can just add the history relationship in User model like this:

```
public function histories(){ 
return $this->hasMany('App\History'); // depending on the namespace of the History model.
}
```

so, In the HistoryController, you can can put:

```
public function search($user_name){
$result = User::search($user_name)->with('histories')->get();
return $result;
}
```

or if you insist to use History model, just define the relationship in it:

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo('\App\User');}
```

and the scopeSearch function:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $term){
    return $query->whereHas('user', function($q) use($term){
        $q->where('name', 'like' , '%'.$term.'%');
    })->with('user')->get();
}
```

note: I dont know the nature of relation between histories and users tables. I just suggest that a User has many histories and History belongs to a User.
if it is not the case, just change the type of relationship in models to whatever adequate.

Hope that can help.

Comment: I am trying to display users' histories, but let me try thinking about it

Comment: tried moving it, It wasn't as simple as you think, need to think about user's relationship... because I'm using HistoryController to display those histories.. Still messing with the query and stucked..

Comment: Your guesses are right, I've already had:
user has many histories,
history belongs to a user.
Your complex queries work well. I've never seen such queries. I'm gonna dive deeper into queries after this. 
Thank you very much, you've concluded my 2 days of solving a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what you've provided:

```
$result = $query->where('user_id', 'like', '%' .$term. '%');
return result;
```

You're always going to be searching for the `user_id`, so of course it will only return something when somebody enters an `id`.

Have a look here to read about Query Scopes:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes

But it looks like you'd need something like this in your History model:

```
public function scopeOfType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->whereType($type);
}
```

Comment: Yes right now it only works to search based on user_id. I want to access user->name in History model while only having user_id in it but I got lost

Comment: Thank you for the link though, I though scopeSearch is a pre-defined function, you woke me up from a nightmare.